# Adding ng-model to div using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I started with angular and I have a problem. I have this div. it contains div which displays `{{stored}}` value from angular [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript). When you type something inside a text box and clicks the button.

```
<div>
  <div id="hidestore">{{stored}}</div> <input id="dobind" type="text" />
  <input type="button" id="showstore" value="show" />
</div>
```

It calls this [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery)code which adds `textbox` a `ng-model` which corresponds to the {{stored}} above.
Basically I want div to display `{{stored}}` value from the time where the button is pressed (without using `$scope`).

```
$("#showstore").click(function() {
  $("#dobind").attr("ng-model", "stored")
});
```

Sorry for my bad grammar. I need help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `jquery` in angularjs is a bad practise but it is not that you can't achieve what you are trying. Instead of binding the `ng-model` on show, you need to prebind it. Just hide the `hidestore` div at first and make it show after you click the show button, which has a really good way to [ng-show](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow) in `angularjs`.

```js
angular.module('myApp',[])
.controller('myAppCtrl',function($scope){
        $('#hidestore').css('display','none');
     $("#showstore").click(function(){
        $('#hidestore').css('display','block');
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
 <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="3.1.1" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myAppCtrl">

      <div>
    <div id="hidestore">{{stored}}</div>
    <input id="dobind" type="text" ng-model="stored"/>
    <input type="button" id="showstore" value="show" />
  </div>        
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you for answering the question! I assume $scope is something like $(this) in jquery

Comment: there are different conventions besides $scope that you can use @KentaNomoto . Have fun programming. You can google it out :)

Answer (score 1):

Its not good practice to use jquery with angularjs. You need to create one `s` for input box. and `ng-click` function for button. when you click on button assign input box text to `stored` ng-model.

```js
angular.module('sample',[])
.controller('sampleCnt',function($scope){
$scope.show = function(){
  $scope.stored = $scope.text;
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="sample" ng-controller="sampleCnt">

        <div id="hidestore" >{{stored}}</div> <input id="dobind" type="text" ng-model="text"/>
        <input type="button" id="showstore" ng-click="show()" value="show"/>
    </div>
    
    </div>
```